# ACCESS 2007: If/Or Query Trouble Shooting

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have 5 fields of "keywords" that have been assigned to each record.

I'd like to build a query that will select and identify only those records sharing a common keyword.

So it would be like "show me records than have the keyword "environment" in any of the 5 fields it may say so."

I'm pretty new at this and am a little frustrated.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  * -- or whatever fields you need
FROM tablename
WHERE
  keyword1='environment' -- maybe keyword1 LIKE '%environment%'
  OR keyword2='environment'
  OR keyword3='environment'
  OR keyword4='environment'
  OR keyword5='environment'
```

That said, you should reconsider your DB structure: The canonical way to do this, is to have your table, a keyword table and a jointable:

- Your table has an ID
- The keyword table has the keyword and an ID
- The jointable has yourtable.ID and keywords.ID

This way you can

- attach an arbitrary count of keywords to your records
- keep your keywords consitent ("Theater" vs. "Theatre")
- have a foot in the door for keyword internationalization
- get rid of the query we started with: It now reads

.

```
SELECT
  yourtable.*
FROM yourtable
INNER JOIN yourtable_keywords ON yourtable.ID is yourtable_keywords.yourtableID
INNER JOIN keywords ON keywords.ID is yourtable_keywords.keywordID
WHERE keywords.keyword='environment'
```